# Controlling Raspberry Pi over WiFi in LAN

Tags: wifi

I've searched how to do it, but all that I get is controlling **RPI over the internet.**

**What I want to do** is connect a device (a phone, PC...) directly to the Raspberry using WIFi. Then, control the RPi using an app or a webpage on the browser(Guess this means webserver).

Edit:
By "Control" I mean having an UI in the device connected to the RPI. When I click something on the phone, Raspberry should do something (send a serial data).

But I want to connect the devices **wirelessly**

Comment: Try doing a search for SSH this will give you access to the command line. If your use a PC I recommend putty and if your phone uses android I would suggest juiceySSH.

Comment: This question is too vague. What do you want to actually "control"? As @SteveRobillard has said, `ssh` gives you access to the command line, and you can execute any command.

Comment: You may also be looking for [SimpleComputerRemote](http://philproctor.github.io/SimpleComputerRemote/) which will turn your Android device into a wifi keyboard and mouse. But your question is very vague in terms of what kind of device you're wanting connect to the pi and what you're goals are

Comment: @Dick, if for whatever reason creating two accounts was not your intention you can reach out to us moderators to have the accounts merged.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is connect a device (a phone, PC...) directly to the Raspberry using WIFi.

Either you do that by creating a wifi hotspot on your phone and connect to it with the Pi, or vice versa, create a hotspot on the Pi and connect to it with the phone.  The latter is commonly done with [`hostapd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostapd#Jouni_Malinen.27s_hostapd.5B1.5D).  It will much harder than doing it with the phone, but potentially more flexible depending on the context of use.

There are packages available for Raspbian (see `apt search hostapd`) and most other GNU/Linux distros.

> Then, control the RPi using an app or a webpage on the browser(Guess this means webserver).

Yes, accessing a web page requires a web server to provide it.  Once the two devices are on the same hotspot, you can access the web server using the Pi's IP address.  It does not matter whether the Pi or the phone is acting as the hotspot AP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing xrdp:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

And then enter `pi@raspberrypi.local` (alternatively you can enter your Pi's local IP) into the Windows Remote Desktop feature. It should be preinstalled if you have a computer running Windows.

This will allow you to access your Pi's desktop remotely. 
You can then code an UI running on the Pi using pygame for example.